# How do I change the path to a dropbox folder

Tags: sql-server, permissions, dropbox

I want to move my `.mdf` and `.ldf` into my dropbox folder.

I ran this script command:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase1 MODIFY FILE 
(
   Name = matrix,
   Filename = 'C:\Users\mycomputer\Dropbox\MyDatabase1.mdf'
);
```

But I get this error:

> The path specified by 'C:\Users\mycomputer\Dropbox\MyDatabase1.mdf' is
>   not in a valid directory.

I'm pretty sure it's just a permissions issue where the sql service running my script doesn't have the correct permissions. But I have no clue which object to grant all permissions to my DropBox. I tried mycomputer\users but that didn't work. Can someone help please?

Comment: I *really* recommend **not** to do this -- make a backup, and put the backup in the dropbox folder.  I don't think you understand that the MDF is operated on constantly, and that a backup is a highly compressed point-in-time snapshot of the database.

Comment: I can only support OMG Ponies on this - **don't do this** - it's neither a good idea, nor is it safe. At best, you'll corrupt your database files. SQL Server is **not** designed to have its data files reside on something like Dropbox!

Comment: this is all super helpful. i appreciate both of you chiming in!! so let's say i change course a bit, where i create the mdf and ldf from scratch inside of dropbox. my main little goal is to figure out what the sql manager tool or service Object Names, so i can give the proper permissions to those objects for the dropbox folders.

Comment: Why do you think you want your mdf/ldf files in your Dropbox folder? I have to echo the others - you probably want to do this so you can share these files or access them remotely, but you can't really do this. Instead of asking how to put your mdf/ldf files in your Dropbox folder, why not state your actual goal and ask how best to achieve it? Your follow-up question really leads me to believe you are pursuing the completely wrong path here.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the comment...here goes. My little goal is to: share the ms sql database remotely but securely from 2 different servers. My MS sql server connection string looks like:  connectionString="server=.\My2012;Database=MyDatabase1;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: sorry for being a pain, and ignorant lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `Dropbox` does not make snapshots of the files it copies.

This means the files could (and most probably would) be written to during the copy and they'll arrive in inconsistent state, rendering them unusable.

I believe you would want to use [`Log Shipping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188698%28v=sql.105%29) instead. This is a feature of `SQL Server` which allows transaction logs to be incrementally backed up and sent to another server (possibly by means of `Dropbox`), where they can be restored. This would allow you to have a snapshot of the database on another server.

Comment: Hmm, I really just want 2 or more different servers accessing or connecting to the same sql database at the same time.

Comment: @user1366569: this is impossible with `SQL Server`.

Comment: So I can't have two different webservers on separate machines all accessing the same database? If so, can anyone give me a tutorial for that. I'd like to keep the same database connection string.

Comment: @user1366569: this is impossible. `Oracle` supports it (with `Real Application Clusters`), `SQL Server` does not. What tutorial do you want?

Comment: got it. there is not tutorial for something that ms sql server can't do, bummer.